# Swift not able to return the exact data from jsonResult

Tags: ios, json, swift, google-api

I'm trying to extract book data from the Google Books API:
https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=isbn:9781451648546

I was able to get book title,description and thumbnail but I'm stuck on getting author and category exact informations (without the [" "]).

I'm getting this result with the previous link :

```
Author:["Walter Isaacson"]
Categories:[""Biography & Autobiography""]

    "volumeInfo": {
    "title": "Steve Jobs",
    "authors": [
     "Walter Isaacson"
    ],
    "publisher": "Simon and Schuster",
    "publishedDate": "2011",
```

and using this code on my iOS application:

```
if let arrayOfAuthors = (jsonResult as AnyObject).value(forKeyPath: "items.volumeInfo.authors") as? [[String]] {
            DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated).async {
                // Bounce back to the main thread to update the UI
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.authorLabel.text =  "Author: \(arrayOfAuthors[0])"
                }
            }

        }
```

Comment: You casting value as Array of array of strings with `as? [[String]]` When it should just be an array of strings, `as? [String]`

Comment: using `as? [String]` i didn't recieve anythings

Comment: I can post a solution using [Object Mapper](https://github.com/Hearst-DD/ObjectMapper) If you would like to use a library for JSON parsing.

Comment: @NSGangster just discover that both authors and categories are inside an array so this works for me : `self.authorLabel.text =  "\((arrayOfAuthors[0])[0])"`  thank you

Comment: Nice work. Figured it was something to do with the accessing of the elements.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```
func parseJSON(){
    let backgroundQueue = DispatchQueue.global(qos: DispatchQoS.QoSClass.default)

    backgroundQueue.async(execute: {

        let serverResponseJSON:NSDictionary = self.parseURLToResponseJSON(urlToRequest: "https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=isbn:9781451648546")
        print(serverResponseJSON)
        let arrayOfauthors:NSArray = serverResponseJSON.value(forKeyPath: "items.volumeInfo.authors") as! NSArray
        print(arrayOfauthors)

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.authorLabel.text =  "Author: \(arrayOfAuthors[0])"
        }
    })
}

func parseURLToResponseJSON(urlToRequest: String) -> NSDictionary{
    let inputData = try? Data(contentsOf: URL(string: urlToRequest)!)
    let boardsDictionary: NSDictionary = (try! JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: inputData!, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers)) as! NSDictionary
    return boardsDictionary
}
```